# Google Maps API - Default cursor type

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am dynamically changing the cursor type on a Google Map using the Javascript V3 API.

```
map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});
```

This is easy but I cannot figure out how to change back to the default draggable hand cursor.

Any suggestion of how I can reference the default cursor type.  I have tried default, auto and hand to no avail.  Below is how the hand looks before I change it.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's an Image: http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur

```
cursor: url("https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur"), default;
```

I don't know if it is documented somewhere, but setting the draggableCursor-option to **`null`** will restore the default for me, it could be an better option.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked great.  Changed it back to default using    map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur),default'});

Comment: I found the answer below to be significantly better as it clears the old cursor icon instantly i.e: map.setOptions({draggableCursor:''});

Answer (score 37):

This seems to work for me

```
map.setOptions({draggableCursor:''});
```

Comment: Still the best answer.

Answer (score 9):

I've had some problems to change the default cursor type at Google Maps v3. Whenever you want the cursor set to the hand, use draggableCursor: 'pointer' at the mapOptions definition, but if you want to get rid of the little hand, and you just want to see the standard web pointer, the value for draggableCursor must be 'default', like the code below.

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: position,
    mapTypeId: mapTypeId,
    draggableCursor: 'default'
  };
```

This tool might be of some help: http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html.

Comment: the gmap "hand" cursor is not "pointer" but "grab" (an open hand)